# Is it true reduction in sensitivity to dopamine due to over stimulation from addicting behaviors can be permanent, if yes how come?

Tags: neuroscience, brain, neurophysiology, addiction

I've read somewhat conflicting things.

General concept is this:

`Addiction -> Over product of dopamine -> Reduction/Desensitization of dopamine receptors -> problems`

And if you let go of addiction you go through period of withdrawl that can last from 90 days to a year.

BUT forever for some people... Why?